# spring boot registering rest controller doesn't work without class level requestmapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

boot application, however, even though my service component shows as registered bean in spring context its url is not getting registered. Basically, to register my component which has method level `@RequestMapping` annotation I need to define class level request mapping. And then it spring context is able to register the url handler.

my directory structure looks like;

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── awesomecrypto
│   │   │           └── backend
│   │   │               ├── SpringBootApp.java
│   │   │               ├── entity
│   │   │               │   └── MarketData.java
│   │   │               ├── repository
│   │   │               │   └── MarketDataRepository.java
│   │   │               └── service
│   │   │                   └── MarketDataService.java
│   │   └── resources
```

**SpringBootApp.java**

```
package com.awesomecrypto.backend;

// import statements.

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);

        for (String name: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

**MarketDataService**

```
package com.awesomecrypto.backend.service;

// import statements here.

@Component
public class MarketDataService {

    @Autowired
    private MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository;

    @GetMapping("/marketData")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getMarketData() {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

Without having a `@RequestMapping` defined on `MarketDataService` class level there are no any url handlers registered for "/marketData" url.

```
2018-05-28 15:15:11.357  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-28 15:15:11.357  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1295 ms
2018-05-28 15:15:11.460  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.465  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.465  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.465  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.465  INFO 30618 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.601  INFO 30618 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.813  INFO 30618 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6c65519: startup date [Mon May 28 15:15:10 PDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-28 15:15:11.915  INFO 30618 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-28 15:15:11.916  INFO 30618 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-05-28 15:15:11.939  INFO 30618 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-28 15:15:11.939  INFO 30618 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

On the other hand, `marketDataService` is registered in spring context which doesn't makes sense. Here is the related `getBeanDefinitionNames` logs.

```
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
springBootApp
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory
marketDataRepository
marketDataService
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry
```

Now if I add `@RequestMapping("/test")` on top of `MarketDataService` then spring registers a url handler.

```
2018-05-28 15:20:31.320  INFO 31536 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test/marketData],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.awesomecrypto.backend.service.MarketDataService.getMarketData()
```

I am running application with;

> mvn clean package
>
> mvn spring-boot:run

All of the examples over the web doesn't mention about this and looks like it class level RequestMapping is not required but I couldn't make it. I appreciate for your help. Thanks!

Comment: The right way would be to annotate your class with @RestController.

Comment: You also do not need Component. or ResponseBody annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@GetMapping` annotation is being ignored because there is no annotation of type `@Controller` at the top of your `MarketDataService` class.

In your case, you should use the [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) (which is itself annotated with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`):

```
@RestController
public class MarketDataService {

    @Autowired
    private MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository;

    @GetMapping("/marketData")
    public String getMarketData() {
        return "foobar";
    }

}
```

The usage of `@RequestMapping` on a class is to pass down the given parameter as well as the given path parameter to children mappings in the same class.

For instance, adding `@RequestMapping("/api")` above the class `MarketDataService` would mean that the path in order to trigger the `getMarketData()` method would be `/api/marketData` instead of `/marketData`.

Likewise, if you added `@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = "application/json")`, it would pass down `produces = "application/json"` parameter to `@GetMapping("/marketData")`.

I see `@RequestMapping` being used on the class often when the controller is used to CRUD a given resource, e.g.:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/marketData")
public class MarketDataService {

    @Autowired
    private MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository;

    @PostMapping("")
    public String createMarketData() {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public String getAllMarketData() {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getMarketDataById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("")
    public String deleteAllMarketData() {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String deleteMarketDataById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am aware of using RequestMapping on class level will extend the url path to the method level urls, however, I wasn't aware of I need to either use `@Controller` or `@RestController` to register method level handlers. This fixed the issue. Although I would expect Component should work because `@Controller` annotation extends from `@Component` annotation. Thank again by the way

Answer (score 2):

You don't need RequestMapping at the Class Level. Change your code to this and it will work for you.

```
 @RestController
 public class MarketDataService {

    @Autowired
    private MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository;

    @GetMapping("/marketData")
    public String getMarketData() {
     return "foobar";
    }
  }
```

I would encourage you to read more about Spring MVC architecture.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc

Also you can read the javaDocs for RequestMapping, RestController.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

Comment: Your first link is documentation from Spring 3.2.x, which did not have the `@RestController` annotation yet since it was added in 4.0.

Comment: RestController is nothing more than Controller and ResponseBody together. Convenience Annotation,

Comment: Yes, but if you suggest him to read an article, that article should at least explain the answer you're giving him. Since `@RestController` is not in the first article you suggested he reads, would that not mean that he won't understand the answer you're giving him? The latest version of the first link is the following: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc

Comment: Sure, I wanted him to understand the architecture of Spring MVC

Comment: So, he will know how things work behind the scenes. And it will put him in a better shape, next time he has a issue with Spring MVC

Comment: Updated my answer with the latest link.